# What is the equivalent to Rectangle.Inflate() using a GraphicsPath?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing

I'm developing a WindowsForms application and I need to highlight some figures defined with a graphics path.

```
using Drawing.Drawing2D
```

Is there any similar to `Rectangle.Inflate()` but for the `GraphicsPath`?

I only need to inflate the same value in x and y.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the figure represented by your `GraphicsPath` to appear *bigger*, personally I would use a graphics transform:

```
using (Graphics graphics = /* ... */)
{
    var matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.Translate( /* ... */ );  // put the mid-point of the figure here
    matrix.Scale(1.5f, 1.5f);       // makes it 50% bigger
    matrix.Translate( /* ... */ );  // put the same mid-point here, but negative
    graphics.Transform = matrix;
    graphics.FillPath( /* ... */ );   // or DrawPath

    // Use this to reset the transform if you still need the Graphics object
    graphics.Transform = new Matrix();
}
```

Comment: Incidentally you can grab an approximation of the midpoint using the GraphicsPath's bounding rectangle midpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [`GraphicsPath.Widen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhdhbs59%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but it is not quite the same as `Rectangle.Inflate`.

Basically, it draws the *outline* of a `GraphicsPath` using a specified pen, and then returns you a `GraphicsPath` that represents the area thus drawn.

If you just want to draw the widened figure on the screen, you can always draw both: first the “widened” path, then the original (for the “filling”). But then again, you might just draw the original path’s outline using the same pen...